# when i write the data in the input field and click submit button , it's told me that the data is undefined

Tags: reactjs

wanna take a data from a state in a  component to another component by props

i passed a fx to another component by props, this fx is to take the data from another component and add it to a current state of its component
first component:

```
const ListNames = () => {
const [Nameslist, setNames] = useState([
    { name: 'Abdelrahman', age: 25, id: 1 },
    { name: 'Yasmine', age: 25, id: 2 },
    { name: 'Outhman', age: 10, id: 3 },
    { name: 'Yazid', age: 7, id: 4 },
]);

const addName = (name, age) => setNames(
    [...Nameslist, { name, age, id: Math.random() }]
)

{
    return (
        <div className="name-list">
            <ul>
                {Nameslist.map(name => {
                    return (
                        <li key={name.id}>{name.name} - {name.age}</li>
                    )
                })}
            </ul>
            <AddName addName={addName} />
        </div>
    );
}
```

}

in the another component i take the fx and put in it the data

second Component:

```
const AddName = ({ addName }) => {
const [{ name, age }, setList] = useState("")
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    addName(name, age);
    setList("");
}
return (

    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input type="text" required value={name} onChange={(e) => setList(e.target.value)}></input>
        <input type="number" value={age} onChange={(e) => setList(e.target.value)} ></input>
        <input type="submit"></input>
    </form>

);
```

}

so my problem is when i write the data in the input field and click submit button , it's told me that the data is undefined .

Comment: first, add name to each input. Then `onChange={e => setList({[e.taget.name]: e.target.value})}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const ListNames = () => {
  const [Nameslist, setNames] = useState([
    { name: 'Abdelrahman', age: 25, id: 1 },
    { name: 'Yasmine', age: 25, id: 2 },
    { name: 'Outhman', age: 10, id: 3 },
    { name: 'Yazid', age: 7, id: 4 },
]);


const addName = (details) => {
  setNames(prevList => [
      ...prevList,
      { ...details, id: Math.random() }
    ]);
  };


    return (
        <div className="name-list">
            <ul>
                {Nameslist.map(name => {
                    return (
                        <li key={name.id}>{name.name} - {name.age}</li>
                    )
                })}
            </ul>
            <AddName addName={addName} />
        </div>
    );
}
```

addName.js

```
const addName = ({ addName }) => {
  const [ enteredName, setEnteredName ] = useState("");
  const [ enteredAge, setEnteredAge ] = useState("");

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      addName({ name: enteredName, age: enteredAge });
  }
  return (

      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <input type="text" required value={enteredName} onChange={(e) => setEnteredName(e.target.value)}></input>
          <input type="number" value={enteredAge} onChange={(e) => setEnteredAge(e.target.value)} ></input>
          <input type="submit"></input>
      </form>

  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your input fields should have a `name` attribute.
Here is an example from the W3 documentation for HTML forms: https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_form_submit

In the editor you can try to remove the names, and see that it will not work.